# Dragging dnd items generates "this.manager.nodes[i] is null"

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

I use Dojo 1.3.1, essentially under FF3.5 for now.

I have a dnd source which is also a target. I programmatically add some nodes inside, by cloning template items. The aim for the user is then to use dnd to order the items. It is ok for one or two actions, then I got the "this.manager.nodes[i] is null" error in Firebug, then no more dnd action is taken into account.

My HTML (jsp), partial:

```
<div id="templates" style="display:none">
<div class="dojoDndItem action" id="${act.name}Template">
<fieldset>
  <legend class="dojoDndHandle" >${act.name}</legend>
  <input id="${act.name}.${parm.code}." type="text" style="${parm.style}"
    dojoTypeMod="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
    /><br>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
```

My Javascript for adding/removing dnd items nodes, partial :

```
function addActionFromTemplate(/* String */actionToCreate, /* Object */data) {
    // value of actionToCreate is template id
    var node = dojo.byId(actionToCreate + "Template");
    if (node) {
        var actNode = node.cloneNode(true);

        // make template id unique
        actNode.id = dojo.dnd.getUniqueId();

        // rename inputs (add the action nb at the end of id)
        // and position dojo type (avoid double parsing)
        dojo.query("input[type=text], select", actNode).forEach( function(input) {
            input.id = input.id + actionsCount;
            dojo.attr(input, "name", input.id);
            dojo.attr(input, "dojoType", dojo.attr(input, "dojoTypeMod"));
            dojo.removeAttr(input, "dojoTypeMod");
        });

        // insert the action at script's tail
        actionList.insertNodes(true, [ actNode  ]);

        dojo.parser.parse(actNode);

        // prepare for next add
        actionsCount++;
    }
}

function deleteAction(node) {
    var cont = getContainerClass(node, "action");
    // remove the fieldset action
    cont.parentNode.removeChild(cont);
}
```

Thanks for help ...

Comment: What you have looks ok.  Are you calling sync() on the dojo.dnd.Source after you add/remove items?  Can you post the HTML for your Source?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, seth.
Do you think calling sync() would be better? I thought that parsing was enough.
The HTML source is huge: as I found out that doing "insertNodes(false..." seems to fix the pb, do you really need it ?

Comment: If you are calling the Source methods directly, you don't need to call sync.  If yoiu manipulate the DOM node under Source outside of source, then you should call the sync method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that, finally, simply using :

```
actionList.insertNodes(false, [ actNode  ]);
```

instead of

```
actionList.insertNodes(true, [ actNode  ]);
```

fixed the pb .